# Winform Application installed folder does not contain the XML File to load Data

Tags: c#, xml, winforms

I made a **winform application**,which contain a **listview control**.
**Data** for the listview is loaded through the **XML file** within the code.
when i **debug** the program,the **data is loading from the XML file correctly**.

Created a **setup file** of the same winform application and **installed** the setup with another computer. The **data** is not getting **loaded** because the **xml file** are not present in the setup installed path.

Comment: So, what is the question? Was it your mistake to not include the XML file into the installer? Hm. Yes. Still not seeing a question.

Comment: Whenever we create setup of any program,xml file should be added manually????????

Comment: Well, yes. The only file automatically included is the project output. And a setup project is a dead end - they do not even exist in the current version. Dump that stuff and install WIX - which is the replacement, open source from microsoft. But yes, any payload must be added manually.